# difference between onClick= " return abc() " and onClick= " abc()"

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to inline js and events and facing some issues regarding difference between
**onClick= "return abc()"** and **onClick= "abc()"**

Answer (score 0):

If the function that an `onclick` attribute defines returns `false` it prevents the default behaviour of the click (e.g. following a link).

One example returns the return value of calling `abc()` (which is likely to conditionally be `false` but we can't see the definition of `abc`).

The other always returns `undefined`.

---

Since [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) was introduced in the late 90s and gained widespread support with the release of IE9, the typical approach is to avoid `onclick` attributes, and use the event object to prevent default behaviour instead.

```
const example = (event) => {
    /* do something */
    if (whatever) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};

element.addEventListener('click', example);
```

Comment: I agree with you. But I came across this approach in a coding challenge where I was not allowed to use event listeners. Still thanks for your contribution in clearing my doubt. If you wanna add anything else feel free to do so. As it may help me even more.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses the return value when calling a function in an event to actually set window.event.returnvalue.

This value determines whether the current operation continues:

- When the return value is true, the operation will continue.
- When the return value is false, the operation will be interrupted.
- When directly executed (without return), Window.event.returnvalue
  will not be set, so the operation will continue by default

Comment: yes, the abc() indeed return false; Although I myself prefer event listeners over this approach. But I came across this approach in a coding challenge and I was not allowed to use event listeners. Can you tell me a bit more about it when you say " it will continue the operation if returns true else it will be interrupted" exactly what operations are you talking about?